# PDFRenderer - How can I render a multiple page pdf to a web view or imageview?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I am new to android development and have been looking for a way to render a pdf that I created. Basically I am trying to render multiple pages and then put them all in a webView where I can scroll down and see each page. As of now the code I have below basically displays the first page and it is in an imageView. Each time I have tried to do multiple pages the pages basically all end up on one view with one on top of another.

Please let me know if you have a way of doing this in a webView.
Example code would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance!

```
try {
            File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "document.pdf");
            mPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));

            ParcelFileDescriptor fd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
           // PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(fd);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
            int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
            if (pageCount== 7) {
                Log.v("its right", "its right");
            } else {
                Log.v("its not right", "its right");
            }

                PdfRenderer.Page pages = renderer.openPage(0);
                pages.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                pages.close();

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

       } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("cannot generate pdf", "e");
 }
```

Comment: why don't use some pdf viewers?

Comment: I was not aware of PDF viewers. Do you have any pdf viewers that you would suggest I use? @MehdiKhademloo

Answer (score 0):

```
 // create a new renderer
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

 // let us just render all pages
 final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
     Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

     // say we render for showing on the screen
     page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

     // do stuff with the bitmap

     // close the page
     page.close();
 }

 // close the renderer
 renderer.close();
```

the secret is in render.getPageCount();

Comment: You just copy-pasted the code-snippet from official docs without any additional input (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer).

Answer (score -1):

We can not render the multiple pdf pages by PdfRenderer, PdfRendere create the bitmap of the current page. If you have that requirement then you should implement it by assigning pre and next button. When your current page will be rendered and you are going the next page first page render will be closed.